# Rails - No error when input but output is "nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I intentionally did not include a :text attribute in my Post model. I then did "rails g migration AddTextToPost text: string" to add that column to my posts. In my posts/new I have a text_are :text. I was able to create a post but I couldn't get the :text info. In rails console, @post.text gave me nil. I already did "rake db:migrate" and all. The table is there but it didn't get any information that I put in...Any suggestion and explanations? Thanks

Comment: `reload!` your console..

Answer (score 0):

If your migration `rake db:migrate`has run successfully. Then the attributes should be available in Post model. Either run **reload!** in the rails console or exit using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and then again enter rails console. You should be able to see the updated table changes

Answer (score 0):

In your rails console:

```
reload! # to reload the environment of rails console and it reread the db connected to it
@post.reload # to reload the values of @post(or whatever object name) from db table, basically invalidates the cache and loads the data from db again.
@post.text # get the updated value.
```

Comment: turned out the db:migrate didn't run. It gives me this error: ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time) ** Invoke environment (first_time) ** Execute environment ** Execute db:migrate ** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time) ** Invoke environment ** Execute db:schema:dump. Any idea how to fix this? I tried to do rollback and migrate again but did not work.

Comment: Ask a separate question with the error log you've got on your console. And, refer the question link. I'll see what I can do to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in console @post=Post.last
if its showing the text attribute means that your migration run successfully
Otherwise run rakedb:migrate and reload your console and restart the rails console(ctr+c) and rails s